# All columns in join in ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments
  has_many :tags
end
```

`Category.joins(:articles)` in rails equivalently

```
SELECT categories.* FROM categories
  INNER JOIN articles ON articles.category_id = categories.id
```

if i want have rails-code is equivalently sql

```
SELECT * FROM categories
  INNER JOIN articles ON articles.category_id = categories.id
```

what should I do?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Perhaps some relevant data for input and output would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Category.select('*').joins(:articles)
```

or

```
categoyes = Category.select('*').includes(:articles)
```

and

```
categoyes.each do |category|
    puts category.articles
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `select` method

```
categories = Category.select('*').joins(:articles)
categories.first.some_column_from_articles
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method

```
Category.connection.select_all("SELECT * FROM categories
  INNER JOIN articles ON articles.category_id = categories.id").to_a
```